# Entity Framework 6 NOT recognizing a Foreign Key which exists

Tags: entity-framework-6, foreign-key-relationship

I have a table contacts which has two phones for primaryphone and secondaryphone.  Both of these have fields primaryphonetypeid and secondaryphonetypeid.  These two columns reference the same table phonetype.  No matter what I do, EF will not recognize the secondaryphonetypeid as a foreign key.  I have even removed the primaryphonetypeid from my code and killed its foreign key constraint and it still says the secondaryphonetypeid does not exist.

```
[Table("PhoneType", Schema = "lkp")]
public class PhoneTypeEntity
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Column("PhoneTypeId")]
    public int PhoneTypeId { get; set; }

    [Column("PhoneTypeName")]
    public string PhoneTypeName { get; set; }        
}

public class ContactEntity
{

    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Column("ContactId")]
    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    [Column("AccountId")]
    public int? AccountId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AccountId")]
    public virtual AccountEntity Account { get; set; }
    [Column("ContactTypeId")]
    public int? ContactTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContactTypeId")]
    public virtual ContactTypeEntity ContactType { get; set; }

    [Column("FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Column("LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Column("EmailAddress")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Column("PrimaryPhone")]
    public string PrimaryPhone { get; set; }

        [Column("PreferredContactMethodId")]
        public int? PreferredContactMethodId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PreferredContactMethodId")]
        public virtual PreferredContactMethodEntity PreferredContactMethod { get; set; }

        [Column("AddressLine1")]
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

        [Column("AddressLine2")]
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }

        [Column("PrimaryPhoneTypeId")]
        public int? PrimaryPhoneTypeId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PrimaryPhoneTypeId")]
        public virtual PhoneTypeEntity PrimaryPhoneType { get; set; }

        [Column("SecondaryPhone")]
        public string SecondaryPhone { get; set; }

        [Column("SecondaryPhoneTypeId")]
        public int? SecondayPhoneTypeId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SecondaryPhoneTypeId")]
        public virtual PhoneTypeEntity SecondaryPhoneType { get; set; }


    }
```

As you can see there are other foreign keys in this table and they all work fine.

Here is the table with the constraints.  No matter what I have tried, it will not recognize SecondaryPhoneTypeId as a foreign key in entity framework.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contact](
    [ContactId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AccountId] [int] NULL,
    [ContactTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PreferredContactMethodId] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AddressLine1] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [AddressLine2] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [PrimaryPhone] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [PrimaryPhoneTypeId] [int] NULL,
    [SecondaryPhone] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [SecondaryPhoneTypeId] [int] NULL,
    [State] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [EmailAddress] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [PostalCode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [IsMilitary] [bit] NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [City] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ContactDetail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ContactId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contact]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Contact_Account] FOREIGN KEY([AccountId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Account] ([AccountId])
NOT FOR REPLICATION 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contact] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Contact_Account]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contact]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Contact_ContactType] FOREIGN KEY([ContactTypeId])
REFERENCES [lkp].[ContactType] ([ContactTypeId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contact] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Contact_ContactType]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contact]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Contact_PreferredContactMethod] FOREIGN KEY([PreferredContactMethodId])
REFERENCES [lkp].[PreferredContactMethod] ([PreferredContactMethodId])
NOT FOR REPLICATION 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contact] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Contact_PreferredContactMethod]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contact]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Contact_PrimaryPhoneTypeId] FOREIGN KEY([PrimaryPhoneTypeId])
REFERENCES [lkp].[PhoneType] ([PhoneTypeId])
NOT FOR REPLICATION 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contact] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Contact_PrimaryPhoneTypeId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contact]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Contact_SecondaryPhoneTypeId] FOREIGN KEY([SecondaryPhoneTypeId])
REFERENCES [lkp].[PhoneType] ([PhoneTypeId])
NOT FOR REPLICATION 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contact] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Contact_SecondaryPhoneTypeId]
GO

    enter code here
```

Comment: To be clear, you are having problems referencing the 2nd foreign key as opposed to configuring it via code first? Might be helpful to see the query and the SQL it generates.

Comment: yes, I'm having problems with the second foreign key.  I will look at the query generated to see what I can see.

Comment: Here is the error.  It doesn't generate sql, it craps out on the foreign key, which exists.   The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'SecondaryPhoneType' on type 'DataAccess.Entities.ContactEntity' is not valid. The foreign key name 'SecondaryPhoneTypeId' was not found on the dependent type 'DataAccess.Entities.ContactEntity'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.